# Date from String not Set in UIDatePicker Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uidatepicker

I want to set the datepicker date from string.I have a multiple date in view and I am using  Date picker via IBOutlet for Different string date but some time datepicker not display the date based on string below is my code.

```
var strDate : String!= "06:45 AM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate)
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
self.datePicker.setDate(date!, animated: false)
```

Comment: check if `self.datePicker` is not nil at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked you code and date is nil. After adding a locale date is not nil:

```
var strDate : String!= "06:45 AM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate)
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
self.datePicker.setDate(date!, animated: false)
```

Comment: yeah its working now  I have used dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en") identifier after using "en_US_POSIX" this identifier now its work !!! thanks man I appricate